# MySQL5.5 If Statement

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL55 on MySQLWorkbench 6.2 for Windows,

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `maxBBLimit`;
CREATE TRIGGER `maxBBLimit`
AFTER UPDATE ON locationobject
FOR EACH ROW
IF locationobject.boxLowY > 1000 THEN CALL RaiseException();
END IF;
```

Assuming that `locationobject` has a unsigned int variable called `boxLowY` that only allows values between 0 and 1000, and if it is above this range, it calls `RaiseException()`.

My workspace refuses to compile because of these errors:

```
17:43:40    CREATE TRIGGER `maxBBLimit` AFTER UPDATE ON locationobject FOR EACH ROW IF locationobject.boxLowY > 1000 THEN CALL RaiseException() Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4    0.000 sec
```

^ This one has a red squiggle under `)` after `RaiseException(`

```
17:43:40    ; END IF    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; END IF' at line 1    0.000 sec
```

^ This one has a red squiggle under `END` in the `END IF` statement;

Anyone have any suggestions how to get this code to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers definitions should be surrounded by `delimiter` statements.

In addition, you refer to the table for the trigger using `new`.  And, you want a `before update` trigger.  If you fail after the `update`, the bad value will still go into the database.  And, you normally use `signal` to return an error.  So, if I haven't missed anything:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `maxBBLimit` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `maxBBLimit`
AFTER UPDATE ON locationobject
FOR EACH ROW
    IF new.boxLowY > 1000 THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '4500' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'boxLowY out of range';
    END IF$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What do you mean by refer to the table with new? Also, there is a new error stating "Create is not allowed at this location" or something like that

Comment: Nvm, I restarted MySQL and it works now. Thanks.

Summary: Use Delimiters